# CSS gap issue in div element

Tags: css

The items are not listed in order there is a gap between item listed how to fix this.

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/sphfig

```
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <div class="tg-topcity">
                    <figure class="tg-cityimg">                                 
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $cat_image ); ?>" alt="<?php esc_html_e('City Image', 'listingo'); ?>">                                   
                        <figcaption>                                        
                            <h3><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $value->term_id, 'cities' ) ); echo esc_attr( $custom_url  ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr( $value->name ); ?></a></h3>
                            <span><?php echo esc_attr( $total_users ); ?>&nbsp;<?php esc_html_e('Listings', 'listingo'); ?></span>                                      
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } } ?>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.tg-topcity, .tg-popularcities {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, Emma! This sounds like a CSS-specific question. You might try asking on StackOverflow or inspect the elements to toggle styles on and off to find out what is causing the gap and how to fix it, but I would suspect it may have to do with Bootstrap's styles, since their column styles are used on the outer wrapper.

Comment: Hi @WebElaine I have posted question on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62069439/css-gap-issue-in-div-element if you know the solution please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem sounds to be related to CSS, try using the following solution:

```
.tg-topcity, .tg-popularcities {
    width: 100%;
    display :inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

or you may also try this instead:

```
.tg-topcity, .tg-popularcities{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @TutsPie the second suggested solution solved my problem.

Comment: kindly vote up for me thanks :p